# Struggling with Syntax regarding structs

Tags: c, struct

So I have 2 structs.  1 is a intStk and the other is an intStkNode.  intStk contains the size of each array in the node and the head, which is the intStkNode that was created most recently.  The intStkNode will contain a tos int, which is the index it is at, the contents, which is an array of ints of size that is contained in the intStk, and a next, which is a int to the next Node below.

So if I have 1 node and it is of size 5, the head will point to this node and the node will have an tos of 0, an array of size 5 all null, and a next to -1.

If there are two nodes and size five, the new node will have a tos of 1, array of size 5, and next of 9.  The intStk head will now point to the one with a tos of 1.

Here is what my code is so far and my questions below it.

```
struct intStack {
    unsigned int allocatedSize;
    struct intStackNode * head;
};

struct intStackNode {
    unsigned int tos;
    int * contents;
    int next;
};

struct intStackNode *
makeNewNode(intStack * stk) {
    struct intStackNode * newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct intStackNode));
    int currentLocation = stk->head->tos;
    //this is not complete yet.
    return newNode;
}

intStack *
stkCreate(unsigned int size) {
    intStack * stk = malloc(sizeof(intStack));
    stk->allocatedSize = size;
    struct intStackNode * intStk = malloc(sizeof(struct intStackNode));
    intStk->tos = 0;
    stk->head = 0;
    int * intStk->contents[size];
    intStk->next = -1;

    return stk;
}
```

Questions.

1. Is the syntax of int currentLocation = stk->head->tos; correct?  Will this return 0 in the first example and 1 in the second?
2. Is the syntax of stk->head = 0; doing what I want it to do?  This is during the creating phase so it will point to the node with tos of 0 every time but it seems weird to me.
3. int * intStk->contents[size]; is not working. This is where the array has its size determined depending on what is passed.  I get this error and it doesn't make sense to me.

   intstk-l.c:33:14: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘->’ token

   int * intStk->contents[size];

Comment: Your text discusses `intStk`; your code has `intStack` — consistency is important in programming.

Comment: Your program has syntax errors, there's no point asking about algorithm correctness until those are resolved.

Comment: "int * intStk->contents[size]; is not working" Right, it makes no sense. What do you want it to do?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! :) Please go here: [SO editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and improve your formatting a little: For instance, format *all* literal code to actually look like code.  
The way it is right now, people aren't likely to give (good) answers, because it's hard to read - and I think your wording might be a little confusing to anyone who does `C` programming.  
Looks like you've put in a little effort, though. So, good luck!

Comment: You have a very curious structure.  The `next` element is confusing me.  Is your stack an array or a linked list?  If a linked list, you seem to be missing the links (shouldn't `next` be an `struct intStackNode *`?).

Comment: My questions are all regarding the syntax, I don't ask about the algorithm at all.  And @n.m. This is just where I want to set the max size of the array to whatever was passed into the function.  They will all be null when it is created.

Comment: Your first question isn't about syntax, it's about code semantics, despite your misuse of the word syntax. A syntax problem with your code will most definitely be highlighted by your compiler.

Comment: I apologize for misusing the term.  I guess that is why I am here trying to figure out why it is wrong.  @JonathanLeffler, yes you are correct.  I don't know what I was thinking.  How would I handle the first one then, since it wouldn't be pointing to anything.

Comment: Normally, you use a NULL pointer when there's nothing to point at.

Comment: That is simple enough.  Did you have time to look at my 3 questions?

Comment: Your identifiers suggest you are trying to create an stack of ints, yet the question talks about a stack of int arrays. Since neither linked list code nor array code are not near anything that resembles correctness, what about concentrating on one data structure at a time? Pick linked lists *or* arrays, get working knowledge of the subject, then move to the next subject. Struct syntax is a secondary issue, it doesn't matter since you haven't sorted out more basic notions yet.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing.  I haven't even touched the linked list part of it.  I am focusing mostly on creating the initial node and having head point to it.  I allocate space for the intStack, set allocatedSize to size.  That takes care of that.  Then I allocate space for the node.  Set tos to 0, set next to Null, and the problem is setting up the array.  Is it simply intStk->contents[size] instead of int * intStk->contents[size]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question. Updating your existing question is strictly for making the question better. It should not be changed in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: sorry, new to this.  Thats my fault.  I will update it back to where my question was so that it can hopefully help others.  Can you quickly look over those two functions before I do it just to say if what I have should work now.  I think my createNewNode works for creating the linked list part of it.

Comment: It was already rolled back by others, several times. You keep changing it. I have rolled it back again.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to your questions, in the proper order and without immediate fixes, are as follows:

> Is the syntax of stk->head = 0; doing what I want it to do? This is during the creating phase so it will point to the node with tos of 0 every time but it seems weird to me.

It's setting the pointer `stk->head` to be a null pointer. It's not pointing anywhere. Which bring us to the next question.

> Is the syntax of int currentLocation = stk->head->tos; correct? Will this return 0 in the first example and 1 in the second?

Since `stk->head` is a null pointer immediately after creation, the attempt to dereference it's `tos` field makes the behavior of your program undefined.

> int * intStk->contents[size]; is not working. This is where the array has its size determined depending on what is passed.

No it isn't. The `contents` field of `struct intStackNode` is a pointer. You cannot redefine it as an array, and this is not how you could allocate space for an array that this pointer can point to. That entire line is all kinds of wrong.

Other then that, your code has (not so) subtle bugs in the form of not checking the return value of `malloc`, and assuming it will always succeed.

---

To address the two issues:

1. You already allocate a `struct intStackNode`, so set `stk->head` to point at it:

   ```
   struct intStack * stk = malloc(sizeof *stk);
   if(stk == NULL) {
     // handle allocation error somehow.
     // return from function or abort program.
     // Do not just continue as if all is well.
   }

   stk->allocatedSize = size;
   stk->head = malloc(sizeof *(stk->head));

   if (stk->head == NULL) {
     // another error to handle. Don'e leak resources.
     free(stk);
     // handle the error
   }
   ```
2. If you want `stk->head->contents` to point at a `size`-full of ints, you need to allocate them as well:

   ```
   stk->head->contents = malloc(sizeof *(stk->head->contents) * size);

   if (stk->head->contents  == NULL) {
     free(stk->head);
     free(stk);
     // You know the drill, handle the error.
   }
   ```

Comment: So I updated my original post with changes I made from both what you say and how I normally handle mallocing.  I think its similar and does the same thing.  I am not getting errors anymore, but does everything do what I explained they need to do?  At the end of this code will there be a intStack with a size of variable and a pointer to the first node and will the node have the 3 components of a tos of 0, an array of variable spots for ints, and a next of null?

Answer (score 0):

These are *formal* answers to your questions. I promise they are correct, bit I cannot promise they will help you in any way.

> Is the syntax of int currentLocation = stk->head->tos; correct?

Yes.

> Will this return 0 in the first example and 1 in the second?

It cannot return anything at all until your entire program is at least syntactically correct. Assuming you fix just the syntax errors, it cannot return anything in the first example because there are no nodes in the list. The head pointer doesn't point to any node; see below. Assuming you fix that, it cannot return anything in the second example with two nodes since there's always one node. The program never links two or more nodes to form a linked list. Given the declaration of `struct intStackNode` it cannot do so.

> Is the syntax of stk->head = 0; doing what I want it to do? This is during the creating phase so it will point to the node with tos of 0 every time but it seems weird to me.

No, it will not point to the node with tos of 0, or any other node. 0 is a special constant that makes a pointer point to no valid object. Normally it is spelled NULL in C to avoid confusion.

> int * intStk->contents[size]; is not working. This is where the array has its size determined depending on what is passed. I get this error and it doesn't make sense to me.

The syntax is not correct. To allocate an integer array of size `size` you do this:

```
 intStk->contents = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: updated my original post with changes I made.  I think I got it working.  I obviously won't know until I try to get createNewNode completed